# Why is my ethernet port not coming up upon bootup on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, 22.04, ethernet

I have had Ubuntu 22.04 LTS working properly since its release a year ago.  Now, after running my daily updates, the single ethernet port I use (eno1) no longer comes up upon bootup.  If I go to Settings -> Network in Gnome (42.5) I can select the port and it instantly comes up and works fine.  So I guess what I am asking is which service upon bootup commands the ethernet port to become active?

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit too quick on the draw submitting this question.  In Gnome, I went to Settings -> Network and selected options for the ethernet interface and discovered that "Connect Automatically" was unchecked.  I am unsure how this happened.  But checking that option corrected the issue upon reboot.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting an answer.